# Labels are wrongly going underneath inputs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Exactly as the title says, except labels are not placed fully below them. i'm just making a login page over bootstrap and  it turns out labels and inputs styled with bootstrap are the source of this problem. I checked if there could be any typo or misfollowed bootstrap doc on this, but it wasn't that as far as i'm aware. I think this info is enough to come up with an answer, if not so, please let me know.
By the by, i'm using django for the backend.

NAVIGATOR: Google Chrome

**GOAL:** Labels are fully displayed and correctly aligned beside their respectives inputs.

**RENDERED TEMPLATE IMAGE**
[image]

**RENDERED TEMPLATE CODE**

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/accounts/css/login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script defer="" src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="" src="/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
    <div class="login-area my-5 border-dark border rounded">
        
        <div class="image-area border border-top-0">
            <img src="/static/accounts/images/user.svg" alt="">
        </div>

        <form class="" method="POST">

            <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="FKM9D1moYiiOXKvq1gedhgYfa6A5I5ZYQTdSOiY1uBKaHLicQAN1PXZR4GvsgdAL">
            <div class="form-group row mb-3 mt-5">
                <label for="#username-field" class="col-form-label col-2">Username</label>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="#username-field" name="username">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row my-3">
                <label for="#password-field" class="col-form-label col-2">Password</label>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <input type="password" id="#password-field" class="form-control" name="password">
                </div>
            </div>

            
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center my-5 ">
                <button class="btn btn-primary font-weight-bold py-2 px-4">Submit</button>
            </div>
            
        </form>

        <div class="links-area my-4">
            <a href="" class="link-primary text-decoration-none my-2 d-block">Forgot your password?</a>
            <a href="/accounts/sign-up/" class="link-primary my-2 text-decoration-none d-block">New here?</a>
        </div>
        
    </div>

</body></html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, body * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
          box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.login-area {
  padding: 20px;
}

.login-area .image-area {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.login-area .image-area img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: center;
     object-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your labels are being clipped because you fixed their width by using `col-2`.  Use `col-auto` instead so the width is determined by its content. You've also fixed the width on the input div with `col-10`.  Change this to `col` to span the remaining width of the row.

```
<div class="form-group row mb-3 mt-5">
    <label for="#username-field" class="col-auto col-form-label">Username</label>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="#username-field" name="username">
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not my intention, what i truly want is to align each label beside its  respective input element. As you may see, labels are displayed  beside, but a little under their inputs.